# Worker was sent to a store he was fired from but wasn't allowed to complete his job. New employer fired him as result

Tags: canada, is-x-legal, labor-law, british-columbia

This is a theoretical situation. A person had worked at a retail store. He was terminated without cause and with severance. A few years later the same person is working for a marketing company on a part time basis. On one shift the company sends him to the retail store he was terminated from. An hour after arriving, he is told by his manager (by phone) that he has to leave, and is told by the new store manager that he was trespassing and had been banned. There had been no prior discussion about being banned. The marketing company immediately terminated him and canceled his future shifts due to the single "complaint" from the store. There was no notice, explanation or severance pay.

Have any laws been broken? Does the worker have recourse against the marketing company or store? Does it make a difference if he was a part time employee or contractor? Does the worker have a right to know what the store had said about him to see if it was slander?

Comment: Was the hypothetical worker employed for less than 3 months?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim more than 3 months, but some months he got no work at all.

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of this answer I am assuming that Bob is an employee. If Bob was a contractor then Employer could simply stop assigning him shifts. I am also assuming he has worked there more than 3 months as under BC law employees with less than 3 months service can be dismissed without cause without notice/severance. I'm also assuming that no illegal discrimination took place here**.

The short answer is this all looks legal and Bob would have difficulty fighting it.

A private business can refuse admittance to anyone for any reason. Even if Bob personally considers it unjust, they are not obliged to serve him. As it is private property, being on the premises was indeed trespassing.

This would likely be sufficient for Termination With Cause. Realistically, any action severe enough to get banned from a store would be more than enough to constitute gross misconduct. I work in retail and have only ever seen it happen for theft or aggressive behaviour. "Breaking Company Rules" is also considered Just Cause and in this case the company has a rule of "don't piss off the clients so much they complain, much less eject you".

Bob does not have a legal right to know what happened in a private conversation. It's possible the store didn't even give details beyond "Bob was barred from the premises."

*Hypothetical male characters are called Bob- that's just how it is.

**Ammend "except illegal discrimation" whenever I say "for any reason"

Comment: The implication in the question is potentially that the employee didn't do anything while on the premises for the marketing company.  That is, any potential reason to be banned happened while (still) employed by the store.

Comment: I have a few related questions. Please tell me if they would be better as separate questions.

Comment: "For purposes of this answer I am assuming that Bob is an employee." What if Bob was a contractor and had already been assigned several shifts in advance?

Comment: "A private business can refuse admittance to anyone for any reason." Can they also remove a person for any reason, after they had been allowed to enter?

Comment: Does kicking someone out or banning them require any sort of administrative work or formal notice? Or is it enough for a manager to verbally say "you are banned"?

Comment: Can a company argue they have a "one strike policy" where any complaint leads to termination? If yes, would it not be a valid grievance that one would not have accepted the work (and turned down/cancelled other work) if that had been made clear up front?

Comment: Probably better to keep them separate. It's hard enough to pretend this is hypothetical as it is.

Comment: @StumpTheCheff2 If the company had a secret policy that was never divulged to the employee it would be difficult to enforce.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim OK, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/93084/terminating-an-independent-contractor

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim This question seems less than hypothetical give https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/191714/50253, which you answered .. lol

Comment: @PeterM The question uses the right magic words to pretend. Maybe OP was inspired by that question...